# to insert only date in dd/mm/yyyy format from textbox.error while inserting dates in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

'  Code For Insert query to insert data.'

```
   Try
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "Insert * into test"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Query = "Insert into test(name,date,d1,d2,d3)values(@name,Getdate(),Convert(varchar,@d1,103),Convert(varchar,@d2,103),Convert(varchar,@d3,103))"
    'Convert Function used to insert date in dd/MM/yyyy format'
        cmd = New SqlCommand(Query, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TextBox2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TextBox3.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@d3", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TextBox4.Text

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       con.Close()
       lblvalid.Visible = True
        lblvalid.Text = "Record is inserted successfully"

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblvalid.Text = (ex.Message)

    End Try
```

'while inserting value in datetime.I want to insert in only date form'

Comment: sometime the code works properly and data is stored.But sometimes it gives error.This is the error--The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value. The statement has been terminated.Kindly tell me where am I going wrong.Please help me with the code.

Comment: are you sure that the date is always valid? can you put your actual date values which throw the error?

Comment: i am inserting dates in dd/MM/yyyy format.eg.29/12/2016.It is showing error as above.how do i convert datetime in dd/MM/yyyy form while inserting dates in textbox.

Comment: you stated that sometimes the code works? so i assume the issue here is improper validation of input data and not the code itself.

Comment: Why don´t you use a `DatePicker` instead of TextBoxes? You wouldn´t have to validate any user data and could store the date into the db as a date not as a varchar.

Comment: Can we use datepicker in vb.net web application.i am unable to find it in toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inserting date into ms-sql server then apply anyone of tow concept.

The basic solution is that you have to provide date into either mm/DD/YYYY format or in YYYY-MM-DD date format into ms-sql query.

So, before passing date to query convert your date into either mm/DD/YYYY format or in YYYY-MM-DD format.

To convert date from custom format to m/D/yyyy you can use following function.

```
Imports System.Globalization

Public Function GetMDYFrmCustDt(ByVal CustDate As String) As String
    Dim tmp As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(CustDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo)
    GetMDYFrmCustDt = GetMDYFrmSysDt(tmp)
End Function

Public Function GetMDYFrmSysDt(ByVal SysDate As Date) As String
    Try
        GetMDYFrmSysDt = SysDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    Catch ex As Exception
        GetMDYFrmSysDt = SysDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
    End Try
End Function
```

So, you need to use following code

```
Try
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim Query As String = "Insert into test(name,date,d1,d2,d3)values(@name,Getdate(),@d1,@d2,@d3)"
'Convert Function used to insert date in dd/MM/yyyy format'
    cmd = New SqlCommand(Query, con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = GetMDYFrmCustDt(TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = GetMDYFrmCustDt(TextBox3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d3", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = GetMDYFrmCustDt(TextBox4.Text)

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   con.Close()
   lblvalid.Visible = True
    lblvalid.Text = "Record is inserted successfully"

Catch ex As Exception
    lblvalid.Text = (ex.Message)

End Try
```

Instead of your code you can use following code, that will provide same functionality without any error

```
Try
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim Query As String = "Insert into test(name,date,d1,d2,d3)values('" & TextBox1.Text & "',Getdate(),'" & GetMDYFrmCustDt(TextBox2.Text) & "','" & GetMDYFrmCustDt(TextBox3.Text) & "','" & GetMDYFrmCustDt(TextBox4.Text) & "')"
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(qry, con)
    da.Fill(ds)

    lblvalid.Visible = True
    lblvalid.Text = "Record is inserted successfully"

Catch ex As Exception
    lblvalid.Text = (ex.Message)

End Try
```

Comment: But how do i convert it before insert query.i have already used convert(varchar,d1,103)function.but it shows error.

Comment: which format you are currently considering in textbox?

Comment: i need to insert date in dd/MM/yyyy format.when i insert date in dd/MM/yyyy format,date gets stored in MM/dd/yyyy format.how to i change it.

Comment: I have update answer that provide you detail information, don't forget to vote up and mark answer please

Comment: Still m getting error as -  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Try to Clean Project, Rebuild Project & then try to run it again.

Comment: it is showing error as--Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime.

Comment: Its not working.Error-The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: error showing- String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Set your system short date format to M/d/yyyy and try again or you can try with DataSet and DataAdapter way which may not give you the error.

Comment: Actually i need to compare the system date with date inserted in textbox.but both are in different format so I am unable to compare it.i need to extract only the date part in datetime datatype.if i insert date in MM/dd/yyyy format,then too m gettimg error

Comment: If you need to compare the system date with date inserted than it is very easy process, first of all keep your system short date format to M/d/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy, then after convert your inserted date into system format and then compare directly by using vb.net functions.

Comment: but the system format is in datetime format.even if in enter date in MM/dd/yyyy format.it automatically displays the time in 0:00:000 fom.So i am unable to compare it.

Comment: You need to accept date from textbox in dd/MM/yyyy format and you need to change your system date format to M/d/yyyy

Comment: if am i using a calender to insert date.it is accepting date value as month in database.what should be the problem?

Comment: When you use datetimepicker, it's value property returns System Date format and if the system date format is M/d/yyyy (i.e. default for windows os) then it's also in form of datetime rather than string.

Answer (score 0):

The much better way would be to use a date picker. The date picker can be easier method for date related input
Here dtpDate is a date picker

```
Format(dtpDate.Value.Date, "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

returns date in the specified format.

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all answers and comments on this page keep converting dates to strings, trying to force the dd/MM/yyyy to a supposed internal MM/dd/yyyy format. 
This is just plain wrong! MM/dd/yyyy is just a locale representation of a date, mostly used in the US , but in no case an internal storage format and all what has been suggested so far is simply converting a String representation into another one.
For this very reason, depending on the database and the computer locales, none of the proposed solution would work with another locale.

The input String value must be converted into a Date format before being submitted to the Parameters.Add function.

The Vb.Net Date class provides a powerful function for converting a known string format into a Date format: ParseExact. 
So, knowing that the imput format is dd/mm/yyyy, your code should look like this:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.ParseExact(TextBox2.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.ParseExact(TextBox3.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d3", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.ParseExact(TextBox4.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score -1):

The standard format of date in database is mm/dd/yyyy. So in your case the textbox date is in dd/mm/yyyy format. so first of all you need to convert your date format into mm/dd/yyyy format. then save it.Then it gives no error. To format a date use below code..

string[] str = TextBox1.Text.Split('/');   //dd/mm/yyyy format

string d1= str[1] + "/" + str[0] + "/" + str[2];  //mm/dd/yyyy format

now save newdate d1 in d1 column.

Comment: This Code is showing error.-Error1-'String' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.
Error2-Identifier expected.
Error5-Argument not specified for parameter 'Number' of 'Public Function Str(Number As Object) As String'.

Comment: `The standard format of date in database is mm/dd/yyyy` that is simply wrong. A date has no format. Only a string representation of a date has a format. And the standard format of a database highly depends on the dbms itself and regional settings.

Comment: I downgraded this answer because, alike like all others on this page, it wrongly assumes the US system locale. See my answer for further explanations.